# Exists solution for this optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Is it possible to solve this optimization problem:
$\max_{\lambda  \in \mathcal{S}^N} x^T W(\lambda) x$ ?

Where:
$\mathcal{S}^N$ is a $N$-dimensional simplex and $W(\lambda)$ is the next matrix:
$$W(\lambda) = \Pi(\lambda) - \Theta^T(\lambda) \Xi^{-1}(\lambda) \Theta(\lambda)$$

and $\Pi(\lambda) = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1 \Pi_1, \lambda_2 \Pi_2, \ldots, \lambda_N \Pi_N), \; \Pi_i =  \Pi_i^T \geq 0 $

$\Xi(\lambda) = \sum_{i = 1}^N \lambda_i \Xi_i, \; \Xi_i =  \Xi_i^T > 0 $

$\Theta(\lambda) = [\lambda_1 \Theta_1, \lambda_2 \Theta_2, \ldots, \lambda_N \Theta_N]$

and $x$ is not given, I know that if exist a solution, it depends of $x$, but intuitively I feel that the optimization is only over the matrix $W(\lambda)$ and I need to make it bigger in some sense.

And I know an upper bound given by Raileight inequalities:
$x^T W(\lambda) x \leq \mu_\max (W(\lambda)) \|x\|^2$.

$\mu_ \max (W(\lambda))$ is the largest eigenvalue of $W(\lambda)$